# Looking for a one-liner to convert x or x[] into x[]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, one-liner

I'm looking for short and valid plain TypeScript one-liner that could replace the following function:

```
function arrayOrMemberToArray<T>(input: T | T[]): T[] {
  if(Arrary.isArray(input)) return input
  return [input]
}
```

Cramming the above logic into a one-line ternary operator is quite messy and hard to follow when chained with other operations:

```
const y = (Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input]).map(() => { /* ... */}) // Too messy
```

`Array.concat` works fine in browser console, but TS doesn't allow it:

```
const x: number | number[] = 0
const y = [].concat(x)
```

```
Error:(27, 21) TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Typescript, and don't have it installed, but what about something like: const y = ((): T[] => [])().concat(x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `concat` solution doesn't typecheck because of the empty array literal. You'd need to write

```
const arr = ([] as number[]).concat(input);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
const arr = [input].flat();
```

This would not only be shorter but also preferable because it doesn't rely on the [concat-spreadable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) of the input but actually checks for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a one-liner, but you can just use the ternary operator:

```
function arrayOrMemberToArray<T>(input: T | T[]): T[] {
  return Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
}
```

Comment: By one-liner I mean I want to replace the whole function by a short one-line snippet, just like the `Array.concat` example does. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
const x: number | number[] = 0
const y = ((): number[] => [])().concat(x)
console.log(y)
```

Comment: Why use an IIFE?

Comment: I don't know anything about Typescript and hadn't seen your other answer in your edit of about 1 minute ago.

Comment: @Bergi So, an actual answer to that question is that I saw function arrayOrMemberToArray could define its output as a typed array, so ... I thought maybe I could do the same with an arrow function.